# Array value manipulation

Tags: php, arrays

I trying to convert array value with word into numeric. Then filtering it with regex and getting original value for matched array element. I have tried in my way. There may be better way to do this.

```
    $arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');     
    $arr= Array
            (
                [0] => 124
                [1] => 8989243three
                [2] => 402three1345233
                [3] => 4023one34523
            );
    $arr2 = array();
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        $v = strtolower($v);
        if(in_array($v,$arrwords))
        {
            $arr2_push()= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text); //replace word with digit and push into $arr_2 . 
        }
    }

    //Now check each value int arr2 to with regex

foreach ($arr2 as $temp){
            $pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
            preg_match_all($pattern, $temp, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

            //If $temp matches with filter then push into $arr3
```

Now getting values from $arr1 which belongs to value in $arr3.

Example: `[3] => 4023one34523` from $arr1 will be in $arr3 as `4023134523`. So value three should be considered. likewise all value.

So bottom line

1. Convert word into number to numeric digit
2. Match number with regex
3. For matched numbers get original value in form of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is mine :)

```
<?php

$words = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
// Hash is faster than in_array, especially on large sets.
$words = array_flip($words);
$test = array(
    124,
    '89889three6four',
    '402one1',
    'five'
);

$b = array();
$pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
foreach ($test as $value) {
    $value = strtolower($value);
    // Capture also the numbers so we just concat later, no more string substitution.
    $matches = preg_split('/(\d+)/', $value, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    if ($matches) {
        $newValue = array();
        foreach ($matches as $word) {
            // Replace if a valid word number.
            $newValue[] = (isset($words[$word]) ? $words[$word] : $word);
        }
        $newValue = implode($newValue);            
        if (preg_match($pattern, $newValue)) {
            $b[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

echo implode("\n", $b);
```

Comment: this is first part only, can you please help 2nd part of mtaching with regex?

Comment: What 2nd part? Sorry but I could not really figure out what you are trying to get.

Comment: you replace word to numeric value. Next step was to filer this number with regex. If it matched in regex then final result should give corresponding value from `$test` in you code. Is that ok for you?

Comment: Aah, so I need to use that regex pattern to test if the converted value matches, then print the corresponding value on the $test variable. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: thanks dude, I am also strugling, raise my question if you feel it will help others

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below code and see if this will help you get closer to what you are trying to achieve:

```
    $arrWords = array(0 => 'zero', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six', 7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine');

    $arr = ['124', '8989243three', '402three1345233', '4023one34523'];
    $arr2 = $arr3 = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $tmpVal = null;
        foreach ($arrWords as $number => $word) {
            if (stripos($val, $word) !== false) {
                $tmpVal = str_replace($word, $number, strtolower($val));
                $arr3[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        $arr2[] = ( ! is_null($tmpVal)) ? $tmpVal : $val;
        $tmpVal = null;
    }

    //Now check each value int arr2 to with regex
    /*foreach ($arr2 as $temp) {
        $pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $temp, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        $matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);
        $matches = array_filter($matches);

        if (is_array($matches) && ! empty($matches)) {
            $arr3[] = $matches;
        }

        unset($matches);
    }*/
```

Comment: can you please check http://ideone.com/6wE9Gs why it is giving such large result in `$arr3`?

Comment: Do you mind quickly explaining to me which values you would like to see in $arr3?

Comment: Yes sure, in `$arr3` I want to see matched values which belongs to `$arr` in your code. Your code is nice, I learned few new thing here. I guess you are almost done

Comment: did you get what I mean?

Comment: I have updated my answer above where I basically each time a match is found populate the matched value in $arr3. I have commented the regex part out incase you would like to build on that. Basically what $arr3 will contain is the values where any replacements where made.